# why pd.Series(np.zeros(len(data))) return NaN?

Tags: python

the dataframe data originally has only one column. Now I like to create another column called 'sup_tolerance' from a zero-filled series like below. However, the returned columns is not zero-filled. It is all NaN values. why? Thanks for your help.

```
data['sup_tolerance']=pd.Series(np.zeros(len(data)))
```

Comment: works fine for me.

Comment: @roudan looks like we are reading the same book! 

For me `np.zeros` **does not** work with Anaconda + Python 3 + Pandas 1.0.5 (pd.__version__).

However I see `np.zeros` **does** work https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/ which uses Pandas 0.25.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*create another column called 'sup_tolerance' from a zero-filled series like below*

You might simply assign 0 and `pandas` will fill it will zeros like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,2,3]})
df['sup_tolerance'] = 0
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   X  sup_tolerance
0  1              0
1  2              0
2  3              0
```

Comment: Thanks Daweo. At the mean time, I am wondering the one I uses doesn't work? I am confused why it returns all NaN instead of zero. Thanks